# Users trading accepts for up votes?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

What's the rule on this? A user asked an ambiguous question, a different user posted an ambiguous answer but one that was as complete as possible given the scant amount of detail in the question. The OP says in a comment that he'll accept the answer if the user up votes the question and a different comment that he made.

[Will my VPS be ruined by Magento?](https://serverfault.com/questions/233077/will-my-vps-be-ruined-by-magento)

Comment: I can't find it now but I thought I had seen something on this subject in an older version of the FAQ. Then again, memory is the second thing that goes.

Comment: @John, I know I've seen something about that somewhere... FAQ, mSO, blog.... can't remember where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not right. Please flag them. Actually, don't worry - I'll deal with it now, but if you see it in future, flag it.